# Pandas DataFrame merge between two values instead of matching one

Tags: python, pandas, merge, between

I have a Dataframe with a date column and I want to merge it with another but not on a match for the column but if the date column is BETWEEN two columns on the second dataframe.

I believe I can achieve this by using apply on the first to filter the second based on these criterion and then combining the results but apply has in practice been a horribly slow way to go about things.

Is there a way to merge with the match being a BETWEEN instead of an Exact match.

example dataframe:

```
,Code,Description,BeginDate,EndDate,RefSessionTypeId,OrganizationCalendarId
0,2014-2015,School Year: 2014-2015,2014-08-18 00:00:00.000,2015-08-01 00:00:00.000,1,3
1,2012-2013,School Year: 2012-2013,2012-09-01 00:00:00.000,2013-08-16 00:00:00.000,1,2
2,2013-2014,School Year: 2013-2014,2013-08-19 00:00:00.000,2014-08-17 00:00:00.000,1,1
```

instead of merge on date=BeginDate or date=EndDate I would want to match on date BETWEEN(BeginDate, EndDate)

Comment: Could you add few rows of data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up realizing I was over thinking this I added a column called merge to both tables which was just all 1's

then I can merge on that column and do regular boolean filters on the resulting merged table.

```
a["merge"] = 1
b["merge"] = 1
c = a.merge(b, on="merge")
```

then filter on c

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.searchsorted()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to simulate *BETWEEN*.

Say your data and lookup value look like this:

```
In [162]: data = pd.DataFrame({
   .....:     'Date': pd.Series(pd.np.random.randint(1429449000, 1429649000, 1000) * 1E9).astype('datetime64[ns]'),
   .....:     'Value': pd.np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000),
   .....: })

In [163]: data.head()
Out[163]:
                 Date  Value
0 2015-04-21 13:37:37     60
1 2015-04-20 06:27:43     76
2 2015-04-20 09:01:51     70
3 2015-04-21 10:47:31      5
4 2015-04-19 18:39:45     27

In [164]:

In [164]: lookup = pd.Series(
   .....:     pd.np.random.randint(0, 10, 5),
   .....:     index=pd.Series(pd.np.random.randint(1429449000, 1429649000, 5) * 1E9).astype('datetime64[ns]'),
   .....: )

In [165]: lookup
Out[165]:
2015-04-21 11:10:39    4
2015-04-21 07:07:51    1
2015-04-20 08:27:19    1
2015-04-21 09:58:42    6
2015-04-20 06:46:12    7
dtype: int32
```

You'd first want to make sure that all dates in `data['Date']` are available in `lookup`'s index. Then, sort the lookup by date.

```
In [166]: lookup[data['Date'].max()] = lookup[data['Date'].min()] = None

In [167]: lookup = lookup.sort_index()
```

Now comes the important bit --  use NumPy's **extremely fast [searchsorted()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) method** to get the indices:

```
In [168]: indices = pd.np.searchsorted(lookup.index.astype(long), data['Date'].astype(long).values, side='left')

In [169]: data['Lookup'] = lookup.iloc[indices].values

In [170]: data.head()
Out[170]:
                 Date  Value Lookup
0 2015-04-21 13:37:37     60   None
1 2015-04-20 06:27:43     76      7
2 2015-04-20 09:01:51     70      1
3 2015-04-21 10:47:31      5      4
4 2015-04-19 18:39:45     27      7
```

EDIT: you might want to convert the Date range you have in your dataset to a single Series like `lookup` above. That's because in case of overlapping date ranges, it isn't always clear which value to look up.